# WinForm looks different in VisualStudio depending on screen

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I developed a WinForms application on a 4K screen PC [Win10, .NET Framework 4.7] by using VS 2013 Professional (Update 5). On this machine there are two screens: the main screen is a 4K one [3840x2160] while the second one is 1920x1080.

Inside VS, the form looks like that on both screens:
[image: Form looks good on the original coding machine]

When I run the related .exe then the form still looks good on both screens!
[image: Form looks good on the original coding machine]

I get the same result by running the .exe on another machine with same characteristics, but just one screen!

I tested my .exe on a 3rd machine [Win10, .NET Framework 4.7, 1920x1080 screen resolution] and here comes the troubles: the GUI appears out of proportion. Moreover, if I maximize it, it doesn't change. I mean, when I try to extend it in order to see lower buttons (*Execute* and *Cancel*) I can't reach/see them. 
[image: Released Form view on the 2nd machine]

Though the `MaximumSize` property has the default value, even when I stretch it out what you see in the above image is what I get (but stretched!).

I reach the same annoying result by running the .exe on other 2 machines [Machine #4: Win8.1, .NET Framework 4.5.1, 1920x1080; Machine #5: Win10, .NET Framework 4.7, 1920x1080].

I tried also to install VS 2017 Professional on Machine #3, open the same project inside it and... here a "funny" thing: also inside VS designer the form looks out of proportion and behaves like .exe when I try to stretch it out:
[image: Bad look inside VS designer on Machine #3]

Is there someone out there who knows what is going on?
I typed for a possible solution, but didn't find any succesful hint.

**Update:**

I've execute some tests by running the .exe on another 4K screen machine (Machine #6) with several combinations of MS Windows Display Settings values.
Here my results:

(  Size of text/apps  ;   Resolution  ;   Does it look good?  )

time0 `-->` ([original] 250% ; 3840x2160 ; Yes )

time1 `-->` (175% ; 3840x2160 ; Yes )

time2 `-->` (175% ; 1920x1080 ; No )

time3 `-->` (125% ; 3840x2160 ; Yes )

time4 `-->` (125% ; 1920x1080 ; No )

time5 `-->` ([back to original] 250% ; 3840x2160 ; (no reboot) No )

time6 `-->` ([back to original] 250% ; 3840x2160 ; (reboot) Yes )

Comment: 4K 3840x3260? Not x2160?

Comment: You are right: 4K 3840x2160. I've updated the A text! Thanks

Comment: Do you have any OS-level magnification set on any of the machines for any of the displays? Also, it'd be useful to include not only the resolution, but also the DPI if you can find it out. It definitely looks like some DPI-related problem.

Comment: I must be honest, I'm a noob in this. The test I've just executed is to get the current DPI setting by using a `System.Drawing.Graphic` instance, and here is what I've got... Developing machine (good one): DpiX= 240; DpiY= 240. Machine #3 (bad one):  DpiX= 96; DpiY= 96.

Comment: 96 is the old windows standard value. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html . For high DPI, the .net framework 4.7 has a helping feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms . Sadly, it will still not make developing dpi-independent winforms elegant or easy.

Comment: What scaling mode are you using? Also, what version of the framework are you targeting? And finally, what scaling options are you specifying for your executable?

Comment: I'm targetting .NET Framework 4.0. Default values are used for other two parameters.